# The class Mock_* was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity [Symfony 5.3][PHPUnit 8.5]

Tags: symfony, phpunit, repository

I am trying to write PHPUnit tests for my Symfony 5.3 project with some Repositories mocked with others real.

```
$ bin/console -v
Symfony 5.3.10 (env: dev, debug: true)
$ bin/phpunit -V
PHPUnit 8.5.19 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

```
Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: The class 'Mock_SType_b1b7aee4' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:23
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:91
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/MappingDriver.php:45
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:156
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:19
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:382
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:85
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:251
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:293
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1789
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1764
/var/www/cir/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:629
/var/www/cir/src/Component/User/UserManager.php:1059
/var/www/cir/src/Component/User/UserManager.php:383
/var/www/cir/tests/Component/User/Manager/Creation/ATCPTest.php:146
```

I have created a KernelTestCase where:

```
$sTypeRepository = $this->createStub(STypeRepository::class);
```

So I tried to use the actual Repository:

```
$sTypeRepository = static::getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository(SType::class);
```

and I get error:

```
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to App\Component\User\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of App\Repository\STypeRepository, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository given, called in /var/www/cir/tests/Component/User/Manager/Creation/ATCPTest.php on line 122

/var/www/cir/src/Component/User/UserManager.php:214
/var/www/cir/tests/Component/User/Manager/Creation/ATCPTest.php:122
```

Other tests run fine for other mocked classes, like here:

```
$this->SUserRoleRepository = $this->createStub(SUserRoleRepository::class);
```

So, why do I get a `MappingException` or `TypeError`, respectively, for some repositories but not others? Perhaps help me to understand the errors better? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my SType entity did not have an accurate @ORM\Entity(...) annotation. I had:

```
/**
 * SType.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="s_type", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_s_type_1", columns={"type_group"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_s_type_2", columns={"code"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SType {}
```

Needed the repositoryClass relation:

```
/**
 * SType.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="s_type", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idx_s_type_1", columns={"type_group"}), @ORM\Index(name="idx_s_type_2", columns={"code"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\STypeRepository")
 */
class SType {}
```